# Why is 3-chip forward current less than 1-chip in RGB LED LTRBR37G?

Tags: led, current, rgb

Why is the forward current of 3-chip operation less than forward current of 1-chip operation? (Page 3 of datasheet.)

https://dammedia.osram.info/media/resource/hires/osram-dam-6751107/LTRB%20R37G_EN.pdf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power dissipation, the package can dissipate a set amount of heat, in page 4 there is a table showing the thermal resistance for 1 chip and 3 chip operation

in other words, you have the dissipation capacity of the chip to the package which limits the power to a single chip and then the resistance of the package which limits the power to the whole device